Is writing to a sparse matrix thread-safe in eigen?
Using Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> Aij datatype, is assignment/update by Aij.coeffRef( row, column ) += val; thread-safe?
I'm constructing a very large, very sparse matrix, and doing it serially is rather slow, so I want to parallelize with openmp [the rest of the code has already been openmp parallelized].
My current parallel approach is to build a vector of triplets (typedef Eigen::Triplet<double> T; std::vector<T> TripletVector( num_triplets ); ) and assign it elements in a for-loop that's parallelized with pragma omp for.
That works fine speed-wise, but there's many repeated (row, column) pairs in TripletVector (they will all show up ~9 times), and I'm a little concerned about memory as I scale up to larger problems, so moving to directly assigning / updating Aij would be helpful.
Thanks!
Edit: Because of how the matrix is designed / defined, I can guarantee during the for loop that each thread is operating on different rows of the matrix, so there shouldn't be any concurrent access issues for a given (row, column) pair.

No, that would a) be slow (each coeffRef call is O(log(n)) for n nonzeros in that row. and b) if the element did not exist before (implicitly zero) it wIll be inserted which may reallocate. I guess you could reserve with an accurate upper limit per column.

I think it's better if you create the CSC format manually and then Map it into a sparse matrix. See here. There is also a version (called uncompressed format by Eigen), that can handle gaps between the allocations per column Might be useful for you

Matrix.insert is actually pretty fast when the indices are sorted. You can also have each thread prepare a presorted vector of values and then do a sequential single-threaded insertion

Thanks! That's good to know about coeffRef being slow for many non-zeros. I'll look into the CSC format, but for now it sounds like the the vector of triplets might be the best approach, since it has been fast so far, and worry about potential memory issues if/when they arise.
